# Automatically delete a copied spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Can anyone help me with this concern?

I have created a spreadsheet and don't want the editors to copy it for any intentions of leaking the information within the spreadsheet. I once saw someone done this before, this should be a script that triggers only once someone copy your initial spreadsheet, the new one (the copied spreadsheet) will automatically deleted once they start typing or making any first change on that file.

I haven't got any code yet but I found this function that delete all the information but don't know how to make it works only on the new spreadsheet once someone copy the original rather than delete the original one.

```
function importDB() {
  //Delete contents of "A:AC" in New Sheet
  var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('INITIAL_SHEET').getSheetByName('TARGET_SHEET').getRange("A:JD");
  sh1.clearContent();

  //Copy new database data
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById('INITIAL_SHEET').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = sh.getDataRange();  
  range.copyTo(sh1.getCell(1,1));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent users from copying a spreadsheet by inserting a script therein.

An `onEdit(e)` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) can clear cells, but the cleared data can be immediately restored simply by pressing **Control+Z**, and the script can easily be disabled by any editor of the spreadsheet, both in the original spreadsheet and in the copy.

In the free edition of Google Workspace, you can use the options in the **File > Share > Share with others** dialog box to prevent *viewers*, but not *editors* from copying the file. See [Stop, limit, or change sharing](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494893#zippy=%2Cprevent-people-from-downloading-printing-or-copying-your-file).

There are additional options in paid Google Workspace domains. See [Set general access options for file sharing in Drive](https://support.google.com/a/answer/12732365).